# Project cannot find RestKit-Prefix.pch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, restkit

I opened an existing project with RestKit.xcodeproj already in the filepath. I went through the installation steps on GitHub like changing the header path and changing the linker flags. When I check the target dependencies RestKit is already listed but appears as a house instead of a target. Under link binary with libraries librestkit.a is listed but appears in red. When I try to build and run the application I get the following errors:

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/anthony/etrak-mobile-apps/iOS/eTrak/Libraries/RestKit/Code/Support/RestKit-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

RestKit-Prefix.pch appears to be in the Support folder of RestKit.xcodeproj but also appears in red

Comment: If RestKit was already included, did it work? If you needed to make changes, did you delete the original and start the installation from scratch?

Comment: The entire project was zipped up and sent to me. I have made no changes and so far I haven't been able to build a working copy. Am I right to assume that deleting and re-installing is my best bet?

Comment: Based on your description I would probably go that route...

Comment: It may be easier for you to just delete RestKit out of the app and install RestKit using CocoaPods. Using CocoaPods the install is very easy, just install CocoaPods, add RestKit to the Podfile and run pod install and your all set. More info can be found here: http://cocoapods.org/ If you do not want to go that route that I would suggest you confirming the file exists at that path using the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

you need definitely another target, just open terminal, go to project folder, check if pod file exists and run pod. RestKit should be install.

Do you have any experience with CocoaPods?